# Get biggest tables and check if column exists in these tables (one query)

Tags: sql, db2

I want to list the biggest tables and also check if this tables have a column LOGSYS.

Like:

```
db2 "Select t.TABNAME,t.NPAGES,(select count(c.colname) from syscat.columns as c 
where c.TABNAME = t.TABNAME and c.colname = 'LOGSYS') from SYSCAT.TABLES as t 
WHERE t.TABSCHEMA = 'OWN' order by t.NPAGES DESC FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY"
```

1. Is this a good way? Is there a better way?
2. The execution is running without ending (or it will end days later... :-( )

The Output should show if one of these biggest tables, has a column named LOGSYS (all tables should list in the output of the sql statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version might be a bit more efficient, since there can be only one column with the specified name in each table:

```
Select 
 t.TABNAME,
 t.NPAGES,
 case 
   when 
     exists (select 1 
             from syscat.columns as c 
             where c.TABNAME = t.TABNAME 
             and c.TABSCHEMA = t.TABSCHEMA 
             and c.colname = 'LOGSYS')
     then 1
   else 0
 end
from SYSCAT.TABLES as t 
WHERE 
  t.TABSCHEMA = 'OWN' 
order by t.NPAGES DESC 
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
```

Note that both `TABNAME` and `TABSCHEMA` are needed to uniquely identify a table.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect that query you have to take very long. Though you could probably improve it by creating an actual join, instead of doing a sub-query (see below), it seems like it should get you what you're asking for. Are you getting any error codes when you try to run your query?

```
SELECT
     T.TABSCHEMA
    ,T.TABNAME
    ,T.NPAGES
    ,COUNT(C.COLNAME)
FROM SYSCAT.TABLES  T
JOIN SYSCAT.COLUMNS C
  ON C.TABNAME   = T.TABNAME
 AND C.TABSCHEMA = T.TABSCHEMA 
WHERE T.TABSCHEMA = 'OWN'
  AND C.COLNAME   = 'LOGSYS'
GROUP BY 
     T.TABSCHEMA
    ,T.TABNAME
    ,T.NPAGES
ORDER BY
     T.NPAGES DESC
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
```